# JSF 2 AJAX - reload whole div (e.g. <ui:include src="toReloadData.xhtml" />)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm working with jsf2 and want to use the ajax-functionality of it. Problem: I've already seen some ajax refresh things. But nothing to refresh a whole div...

I have a xhtml page with data from my bean, and i don't really want to refresh all fields of it, it would be easier to refresh the whole ui:include...

does anybody knows a solution? Or do I have to refresh all fields manually?

best regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put them in some container component with an ID and use it in `render` attribute of `f:ajax`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
        <f:ajax render=":foo" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="foo" layout="block">
    <ui:include src="include.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` renders a `<div>`. If you omit the `layout` attribute, it defaults to `<span>` (only whenever there are any attributes which needs to be rendered to HTML, like `id`).

Comment: I am still confused. So how do you reload the div with id "foo" since `<ui:include src="include.xhtml"/>` is fixed? What if I want to `include` different xhtml file according to some user choice?

Answer (score 1):

Okay BalusC, but I'm still having a problem with the includes and ajax.
my index.xhtml includes a search.xhtml and a results.xhtml
the ajax-part is in search.xhtml and the toRender-id is in results.xhtml...
so at rendering the jsf-tags there's the problem that there's no toRender-Id at this time...

**EDIT:**
Okay the problem was not the arrangement of the includes, it was that the ajax-parts must be in the same form tag like this:

```
<h:form>
  <div id="search" class="search">
    <ui:insert name="search" >
    <ui:include src="search.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
  </div>

  <h:panelGroup id="ajaxResult" layout="block"> 
      <ui:insert name="searchResults" >
      <ui:include src="searchResults.xhtml" />
      </ui:insert>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

search contains f:ajax tag, ajaxResult is toRenderId
best regards, emre