# Reloading div using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555778/jsf-2-ajax-reload-whole-div-e-g-uiinclude-src-toreloaddata-xhtml) topic, where's a bit of code to reload a div using Ajax.
I've tried creating such example, but not successfully.

Here's my code:

- index.xhtml

  ```
          <h:form>
              <f:ajax render=":content">
                  <h:commandButton value="News" action="#{navigationBean.requestPage}">
                      <f:param name="requestedPage" value="news.xhtml"/>
                  </h:commandButton>
              </f:ajax>
              <br/><br/>
              <f:ajax render=":content">
                  <h:commandButton value="News" action="#{navigationBean.requestPage}">
                      <f:param name="requestedPage" value="games.xhtml"/>
                  </h:commandButton>
              </f:ajax>
          </h:form>

      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block">
          <ui:include src="#{navigationBean.viewedPage}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
  ```
- backing bean

  ```
  @ManagedBean
  @ViewScoped
  public class NavigationBean
  {
      private String viewedPage;

      public NavigationBean()
      {
          viewedPage = "news.xhtml";
      }

      public String getViewedPage()
      {
          return viewedPage;
      }

      public void setViewedPage(String viewedPage)
      {
          this.viewedPage = viewedPage;
      }

      public void requestPage()
      {
          Map<String,String> map = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
          viewedPage = map.get("requestedPage");
      }
  }
  ```
- how it looks:
  [image]

So what am I missing? Variable viewedPage is updated, normal labels/texts etc. are updated, but can't get this div working.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
<h:commandButton value="Games" action="#{navigationBean.requestPage}">
    <f:param name="requestedPage" value="games.xhtml"/>
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@none" />
    <f:ajax render=":content"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

plus changing @ViewScoped to @SessionScoped.

Comment: Hi, I am still confused. what will be the panelgroup with id content be now?

Comment: is there anyway to update the content of the other page form using from the other ?