# jsf: change the whole div using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

For now, I have the following structure of the web page:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="navigator"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Literally, the div with id "navigator" is for navigating use. I can choose such as "home", "login", "register", etc. I want to use ajax to refresh the whole div with id "content".

So what should I do?

1) Apparently, I need to have these separate divs. But in what form? Should I use ui:composition or else?

2) What should be the ajax part? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Are you using JSF 1 or JSF 2? Are you using Primefaces by any chance?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda I am using JSF2 and not Primefaces. I have no idea of Primefaces, but will it help me?

Comment: Go through the javaee6 docs to get a good understanding of JSF and its feature

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html

You can find a Template and Ajax example here,

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/

Comment: @AvinashSingh: I have read those two example but it is only refreshing the content of some components, not the whole div. I think they didn't quite answer my question. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Why don't you provide the sample code of what you have done so far

Comment: @AvinashSingh: umm, this is what I got, I am stuck here and I don't know what to do next. Because I need to decide what to use for those different divs.

Comment: I found this that does work:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724397/reloading-div-using-ajax